# ngrx router-store infinite loop

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to add ngrx router-store to my app and have run in to an issue.  Looking at the example app provided on github it looks like I need to just add a routerReducer property to my application state and then register the routerReducer from ngrx router-store.  When I do that the app immediately goes into an infinite loop trying to route to the first page.  this was working fine until I add the router-store.  Actually I can import all the things I need to and it is fine.  the issue is the routerReducer.  once I register that then the problems start.  Here is my state definitions.  I can't figure out what is causing this.

```
export interface App {
  config: AppConfig;
}

export interface RouterStateUrl {
  url: string;
  queryParams: Params;
}

export interface ApplicationState {
  app: App;
  routerReducer: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
}

export const INITIAL_APP_STATE: App = {
  config: {
    Culture: '',
    Dictionary: {},
    Token: '',
    UserId: ''
  }
};
```

Here is the line in my app.module.  If I remove routerReducer then all works.

```
StoreModule.forRoot({app: applicationReducer, routerReducer: routerReducer}, {metaReducers})
```

## Some more info:

I am getting an error when using storeFreeze about _resolveData not being serializeable.  From what I can tell that issue is solved by registering a custom RouterStateSerializer.  I have done that but it is not hit.  I don't know if issue above is related but thought I would mention it.  here is how I am defining that:

```
{provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomRouterStateSerializer}
```

and the class:

```
export interface RouterStateUrl {
  url: string;
  queryParams: Params;
}

export class CustomRouterStateSerializer
  implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
    const { url } = routerState;
    const queryParams = routerState.root.queryParams;

    return { url, queryParams };
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you further explain what is happening in the infinite loop?

Comment: It is throwing the NavigationCancelled event with with the message Navigation ID 320 is not equal to the current navigation id 321.  the ids change each time obviously.  but that message repeats until the browser crashes.  the url it is displaying for that is /dashboard.  I don't know if this is related or not but when I use storeFreeze it throws another error first. t that error is usually related to not having a custom RouterStateSerializer.  I am providing one of those but it is not being hit for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

the issue was my custom serializer.  I made a bone headed mistake and it was getting overwritten with the default one.

Comment: I having a similar issue. Could you update your answer to say what the mistake was?

Comment: I fixed my issue as well. The mistake I made was that I had included `StoreRouterConnectingModule` in two separate modules which was causing the router-store to use the default serializer.

Comment: I think that was also what I did but I can't remember.  It was many lines of code ago.